# SwiftUI -Two Pickers in form: tap on one propagates on the second

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm experiencing an issue using **two pickers** in the same Form/List cell.
If I tap on one picker, the options list is presented but it's dismissed almost instantaneously and the second list is presented... and dismissed too.
I've also noticed that if you use only one picker and other elements in the cell (I've added Spacers to show it), if you tap in any part of the cell, the Picker is activated.
How can I solve this annoying thing?

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var itemIndex: Int
    @State var letterIndex: Int
    var items = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]
    var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                 VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Spacer().frame(height: 40)
                    Picker(selection: $itemIndex, label: Text("Selction:"))
                    {
                         ForEach(0 ..< items.count) {
                            Text(self.items[$0])
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer().frame(height: 40)
                    Picker(selection: $letterIndex, label: Text("Letters:"))
                    {
                        ForEach(0 ..< letters.count) {
                            Text(self.letters[$0])
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer().frame(height: 40)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("My View")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(itemIndex: 0, letterIndex: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you put them in one row? It really violates Form/Picker design.

Comment: The whole section should be "wrapped" inside a rounded corner border. That's the reason why. :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is expected usage of pickers in `Form` - every `Picker` in own row

```
Form {
    Picker(selection: $itemIndex, label: Text("Selction:"))
    {
         ForEach(0 ..< items.count) {
            Text(self.items[$0])
        }
    }
    Picker(selection: $letterIndex, label: Text("Letters:"))
    {
        ForEach(0 ..< letters.count) {
            Text(self.letters[$0])
        }
    }
}
```